# ios Quickblox - customize notification toast color

Tags: ios, colors, push-notification, toast, quickblox

I've integrated Quickblox SDK in my iOS project successfully using this documentation:

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS

When I get a push message, I see a toast as follows:

[image]

How can I customize the background color of the toast?

Answer (score 0):

Customization can be made in the files found in the subfolder `TWMessageBarManager`

For example, to change the colors, modify the method `+(void)initialize` in `TWMessageBarmanager.h`

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    if (self == [TWMessageView class])
    {
        // Fonts
        kTWMessageViewTitleFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
        kTWMessageViewDescriptionFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

        // Colors
        kTWMessageViewTitleColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
        kTWMessageViewDescriptionColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
        kTWDefaultMessageBarStyleSheetInfoBackgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```